# How to display column values in gridview using pivot

Tags: row-value-expression

I want to display dates of particular month in column header of gridview  and

corresponding value should be display under

SELECT

distinct

cardno, name,

min(convert(char(5), time , 108)) over (partition by cardno, CONVERT(varchar(20), time,

102) ) +' | '+max(convert(char(5), time , 108)) over (partition by cardno,

CONVERT(varchar(20), time, 102) ) [exit/in out]

FROM            Events

following is the output of above query

cardno    name         exit/in out
100           baiju         09:30 | 18:30
101           kiran         09:55 | 18:45

i want the output like this

cardno name  2013-07-01    2013-07-12 ...................................2013-07-31

100       baiju   09:30|18:30   null

101       kiran   09:35|18:45   null

means the whole day of month should be display in gridview header .if there is no value it should be null

i tried this example but showing error

declare  @dte as  datetime ='2013-07-01'

declare @StDt as Datetime = DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GETDATE())-1),@dte)

declare @EnDt as datetime = DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@dte)+1,0))

Declare @Cnt as int = datepart(dd,@EnDt)

Declare @inc as int = 0

Create table #temp (Month_date datetime)

while @inc < @cnt

begin

insert into #temp

select DATEADD(dd, @inc, DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@dte)-1),@dte))

set @inc = @inc + 1
end
DECLARE @cols AS  NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([date])
                    from events
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,1,'')

SET @Query='SELECT distinct cardno,name,'+ @cols+'
 from (
    select t.Month_date,e.cardno,e.date
    from #temp t
    right outer join events  on t.Month_date=e.date
) x
pivot
(
    min(convert(char(5), time , 108)) over (partition by cardno, CONVERT(varchar(20), time, 102) ) +' | '+max(convert(char(5), time , 108)) over (partition by cardno, CONVERT(varchar(20), time, 102)

```
for date in  (' + @cols + ')
```

) p
order by Month_date'

exec(@query)

drop table #temp

this is error message

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 19

Invalid column name 'date'.

Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 36

The data types nvarchar(max) and varchar are incompatible in the '|' operator.

how to solve this

Regards

Baiju

Comment: are you trying to apply the pivot in the sql query and bind the resultset to the gridview?

Comment: yes ,my requirement is multiple aggregation in pivot query